# How to test if my server has Safe Mode enabled for curl?

Tags: php, curl

I tried this:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(curl_version());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, what code lets me test if safe mode is activated or not for curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (ini_get('safe_mode')) {
    // your code goes here
}
```